# How to cast two objects

Tags: java, list

I am new in java and i dont know how can I solve the problem.
My problem is that I have a list with sacks  and every stack have persons inside and the persons a string(Name). so list -> stack-> person with name

My question is how can I get the name?

`((Stack)list.getObject()` getObject gives me the current object in the list(this works) but I have no idea for the name :`((Stack)list.getObject().(Person)stack.top().Name` was one idea but it's wrong

Comment: The `.` operator has a higher precedence than the cast operator.  You have to use parens.

Comment: Please do not vandalize the question. If you want to delete it please just do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had the right idea but the wrong syntax. Try this way:

```
Stack stack = (Stack) list.getObject();
Person person = (Person) stack.top();
String name = person.Name;
```

Comment: I like this better than a one liner because it's easier to read and follow

Answer (score 0):

You just need more brackets but it's easier to put as different line.

```
((Person)((Stack)list.getObject()).stack).top().Name
```

Comment: Might want to look at your parenthesis again, you have too many and also in the incorrect spots

Comment: Yup. just realized. Thanks.

Comment: but the rest of the code doesn't make any sense. That would never compile **UPDATE** and now you fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Another option is:

```
((Person)((Stack)list.getObject()).top()).Name
```

However, this isn't all that readable, so let's break it down by the steps that we take to get this:

Get the object:

```
list.getObject()
```

Cast this to a `Stack` object:

```
(Stack)list.getObject()
```

Call `top()` on the stack (note parentheses around the last so we know what we're calling it on):

```
((Stack)list.getObject()).top()
```

Cast this to a `Person` object:

```
(Person)((Stack)list.getObject()).top()
```

Retrieve the `Name` field (noting more parentheses again):

```
((Person)((Stack)list.getObject()).top()).Name
```

Now, as for readability, I would much more recommend wassgren's answer, but if for some reason you absolutely must have this take up on line, that's how you do it.

Comment: works too thx :) but I had to add stack     ((Person)((Stack)list.getObject()).Stack..top()).Name

Comment: I'm confused - is the object in the list a `Stack` or do you have to retrieve the `.stack` field from said object?